# Strange result for Float

Tags: ruby

```
1.824999999999999.round(2)
# => 1.82
1.82499999999999999.round(2)
# => 1.83
```

I don't understand why the result in the first case is `1.82` and for the latter `1.83`. My desired result is `1.82` for both cases.

Comment: You should read about [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is well known, a floating number in computer has errors. Notice that both numbers that you have are close to `1.825`. In your first case, the number is small enough to be differentiated from `1.825`.

```
1.824999999999999
# => 1.824999999999999
```

In your second case, having enough `9`s makes the value close enough to be considered exactly as `1.825`:

```
1.82499999999999999
# => 1.825
```

Then, when you apply `round`, you get `1.83`.

Answer (score 3):

After a certain number of (binary) digits, Ruby cannot represent differences between `Float` literals, even if you've entered the value directly in source code or the console

```
 1.82499999999999999 == 1.825
 # => true
```

If you *really* need a high level of precision, then you could look at the `BigDecimal` class. Although you could still enter enough `9`s to reach limits in that class.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the many excellent explanations here, I'd like to give an example using `BigDecimal`

```
o = BigDecimal.new('1.82499999999999999', 17)
2.0.0p247 :011 > o.round(2).to_f
 => 1.82
```

Also notice that `#round` takes various modes for rounding, as per the docs.

Ref:

1. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-mode
2. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-round

Answer (score 2):

Floats are notoriously imprecise as sawa and Neil have pointed out.

If this is mainly an issue for testing, you can use [assert_in_delta](http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_in_delta) if you're using minitest, or [be_within](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher) with rSpec